# How to after recreate of same sprite, continue touch events

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

i have 2 layers and on ccTouchMoves event i have to destroy and recreate sprite to move from 1st layer to 2nd

i did this something like that

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
            sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.png"];
            [[self parent] addChild: sprite]
            if (sprite)
            {
                [sprite ccTouchBegan:touch withEvent:event];
            //  [character ccTouchMoved:touch withEvent:event];
            }
            [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:true];
}
```

sprite created and called method ccTouchBegan but after that method everything is terminate
**how to call ccTouchMoved and ccTouchEnd just like simple touch event**

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same sprite, why destroy and recreate it? You can just keep on using the same sprite. In [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) I added this method in a CCNode category to transfer ownership of a node from its current parent to a different parent:

```
-(void) transferToNode:(CCNode*)targetNode
{
    CCNode* selfNode = [self retain];
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [targetNode addChild:selfNode z:selfNode.zOrder tag:selfNode.tag];
    [selfNode release];
}
```

The important part is to remove the node (your sprite) from its current parent without cleaning up, so that schedulers and actions keep running. Then just add it as child to a different node (your 2nd layer).

Comment: great idea.. thanks but now his complaining  `@"Delegate already added to touch dispatcher."` that im adding onEnter and onExit touchDelegates how to check is delegate added?

Comment: sorry.... bug fixed http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1267 and thank you